# reasons MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache throwing exception

Tags: c++, windows, memory, kernel, driver

I am a total newbie windows drivers so there may be obvious mistakes in the code.

My code allocates user space dma buffer which work fine accept when a lot of 
buffers are allocated (not necessarily large buffers) on that case 
MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache throws an exception. 
The code stages that fails is  as followed:
1. Use MmMapIoSpace to map physical address to kernel mode virtual address, 
driver can access this virtual address, but its not accessible in user mode.
2. Use IoAllocateMdl and MmBuildMdlForNonPagedPool to build an MDL for the 
mapped physical address.
 3. Use MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache to map the physical pages described by MDL 
to user mode virtual address.

Since our driver will always be the topmost driver, and run in the context of 
the current process, this user mode virtual address is valid to the caller.

code snippet:

```
 phy_buf->kernel_addr =  MmMapIoSpace(phy_buf->phy_addr, phy_buf->size, MmNonCached);


phy_buf->user_mdl = IoAllocateMdl(
        phy_buf->kernel_addr,
        phy_buf->size,
        FALSE,
        FALSE,
        NULL);

if(phy_buf->user_mdl)
{
    MmBuildMdlForNonPagedPool(phy_buf->user_mdl);

    __try{
    phy_buf->user_addr = MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache(    
        phy_buf->user_mdl,    
        UserMode,
        MmNonCached,    
        NULL,    
        FALSE,    
        NormalPagePriority) ;
    }__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {
        IoFreeMdl(phy_buf->user_mdl);
        phy_buf->user_mdl = NULL;
        DbgMessage(FATAL, "MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache failed on EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER\n");
        return NULL; 
    }

    if (phy_buf->user_addr == NULL)
    {
        IoFreeMdl(phy_buf->user_mdl);
        phy_buf->user_mdl = NULL;
        DbgMessage(FATAL, "MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache failed\n");
    }
```

Also how can I get (or print) exact exception that is thrown.

Comment: Are you sure `phy_addr` is valid when the code fails?  I have a vague impression that there's a limit to how many DMA buffers you can have, if you aren't doing the error-checking properly you could maybe wind up trying to map an invalid address.

Comment: To get the exception (NTSTATUS) code, use the GetExceptionCode() function/macro within the except block.